# How can I prove analytically the number $2^{100000}+1$ is not prime??

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I prove analytically   the number

> $$(2^{100000}+1)$$ is not prime??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $x=2^{20000}$. Then
$$2^{100000}+1=x^5+1=(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1).$$

Comment: Certainly do. Luckily taken care of by anorton.

Answer (score 9):

We prove a more general statement: a number of the form $a^n+1$ where $n$ is not a power of two is not prime.

Proof: let $n=2^mk$ with $k$ odd. now let $j=a^{2^m}$. Then $a^n+1=j^k+1$.

Since $k$ is odd we have $j^k+1=(j+1)(j^{k-1}-j^{k-2}+j^{k-3}-\dots+j-1)$

Comment: Except the trivial cases where $a=1$ and $a=-1, n$ even.